# Google Cloud Firestore security rules - rules on document ID

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

If we create new document IDs based on Firebase Authentication user's ID (So that we don't need to query and get document directly from the known user ID), can we create a security rule that we would allow only users who are the owners of such Firebase Authentication user ID to create document ID with such user ID? for example;

```
We have two users as follows:-

Firebase user ID: AAA
Firebase user ID: BBB

Expected results from Firestore security rules

AAA creates document ID: AAA-1 - (ok)
AAA creates document ID: AAA-2 - (ok)
AAA creates document ID: BBB-1 - (not ok)
AAA creates document ID: XYZ-1 - (not ok)

BBB creates document ID: AAA-1 - (not ok)
BBB creates document ID: AAA-2 - (not ok)
BBB creates document ID: BBB-1 - (ok)
BBB creates document ID: XYZ-1 - (not ok)
```

Can we set this kind of rule on Firestore?

Comment: If you save the users id on the document, then it is a simple task. Since you have access to the users ID in the security rules

Comment: What if a user override the document ID on browser?

Comment: You write security rules to disallow that as well.

Comment: Did you find a solution? I am struggling with  the same problem

Answer (score 0):

You can get the request's target document id with `request.resource.id` according to the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/rules/rules.firestore.Resource). Then you can compare it with the request auth user id with something like `allow create: if request.resource.id == request.auth.uid` to restrict the permission.

Comment: In the simulator, it is failing for a create action, though it is working well for an update, or a delete action

Answer (score -1):

It is much better to add a owner field on the document to which you assign the user id who created the document, then just check that field on update eg.

```
allow update: if resource.data.owner == request.auth.uid
```